# Angular - Use Array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array with objects which i get with that :

```
this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => this.MyArray.push(data)
        );
```

But i can't use it with that :

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let ma of MyArray; let i=index">
    <p>{{ma.stuff}}</p>
</ion-card>
```

When i have just one object in my array it work but not with much. 
I think i have to use a foreach to separate each object but i'm not familiar with typerscript syntax.

Thanks for your help !

[Here is my console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVqmc.png)

Console.log in string :

```
   [{
"id_oiseau":1,
"nom_commun":"Hirondelle",
"lieu_signalement":"Foret",
"date_signalement":"2017-05-16",
"condition_signalement":"Aile coincee sous branche",
"date_reception":"2017-05-16",
"date_renvoi":"2017-05-02",
"descriptif_etat":"Aile cassee",
"immatriculation":"EZ654ERRZ",
"etat_actuel":"En attente de livraison",
"image":"bird-profil.jpg",
"id_oiseau_dico":1,
"id_adherent_lpo":1,
"id_acteur":1,
"pays":"France",
"nom_codifie":"HIRON-NANT-4949845",
"id_statut_oiseau":1,
"id_local_lpo":1},
{"id_oiseau":2,"nom_commun":"Moineau","lieu_signalement":"Sur la route","date_signalement":"2017-05-12","condition_signalement":"Sur le bas cote avec trace de sang","date_reception":"2017-05-03","date_renvoi":"2017-05-19","descriptif_etat":"Ne bouge plus sauf la tete","immatriculation":null,"etat_actuel":"Convalescence","image":"bird-1.jpg","id_oiseau_dico":2,"id_adherent_lpo":2,"id_acteur":2,"pays":"France","nom_codifie":"MOIN-ANG-4254545","id_statut_oiseau":2,"id_local_lpo":2}]
```

Comment: what is this.History ?

Comment: It's my array, i forgot to change the name

Comment: `ngFor` **is a `foreach`**. if it "works with just one object" but doesn't work with multiples, then `MyArray` isn't in the structure you are showing here....

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Yep that's why i have a problem, it should work. MyArray is the same structure.

Comment: can you put a console.log and post here

Comment: I just edited with a picture of console.log

Comment: is that MyArray

Comment: Yes it's MyArray

Comment: i don't find anywhere stuff  property is present?

Comment: It was an exemple, "stuff" is like "nom_commun" or "date_reception"

Comment: did u check the answer

Comment: where exactly is this consoled logged? I mean, this cannot be the content of `MyArray`, since it would mean that your data you are not receiving (a list of objects that are **not** in an array). The app would throw error if the data you are receiving would look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer :

```
this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => this.MyArray = data
        );
```

And i put it in the constructor